# python- [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, kaggle

> I'm trying to read images from the specified folder enrollemnts_rgb
> but it gives an error, not in the directory

```
for folder_name in folder_list:
    files_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, folder_name))
    temp=[]
    for file_name in files_list[:no_of_files_in_each_class]:
        temp.append(len(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the error is specifically `Not a directory` not `not in the directory` as your question asserts.

My assumption is your error is actually not in the code you shared. Your `folder_list` probably contains non-folder files. This makes listdir throw an error, as you're passing in a non-folder path.

Check your `folder_list` implementation.

Comment: Did this help solve your issue?